# Macbook Air 2018 / Macbook Pro 13 or any other laptop for web dev

Tags: laptop, web-development

I have a Lenovo (running on Linux) with full hd 15" screen, Core i7 and 8GB RAM and the issue is, that everyday after coding for 8+ hours, I just want to kill myself because I have headaches and really blurry vision (and I'm concerned about long term vision damage because I have 100/100). The issue seems to be the PWM flickering which is set at 200 HZ at this model (I have a really high-end monitor at home and having no issues at all) also battery life is just non-existent at 1.5 hours and after this I dont even want too look at Lenovo laptops, terrible experience all in all.

I'm looking for an upgrade and I know that Macbook Pro/Air, Dell XPS 13 definitely PWM higher that 200hz. So I wanted to ask a question if Macbook Air will be sufficient for web dev or do I need something more powerful.

Also any suggestions on laptops with decent screens and a good keyboard.

Comment: This is too broad for both here and [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).  Web Dev is a very diverse field ranging from simple HTML/CSS coding to in depth PHP and database development.  For me, I do everything on a MBA/Surface Pro laptop and connect to VMs (both on prem and in the cloud via Azure).  My MBA is light and capable and I don't need a ton of "horsepower" because all the heavy lifting is done on a dedicated machine.  So, for us to better help, you need to *define* what it is you're doing with it and evaluate your workflow.

Comment: writing react apps, running a websocket server from time to time on my local machine.